# Что лучше использовать для завершения потока из него же, return@Runnable или thread.interrupt()?

Tags: android, kotlin

И есть ли вообще разница? Оба варианта работают

```
try {
       Thread.sleep(timeout)
    } catch (ex: InterruptedException) {
       return@Runnable
}
```

или

```
try {
       Thread.sleep(timeout)
    } catch (ex: InterruptedException) {
       thread.interrupt()
}
```

Comment: Второе это прерывание уже прерванного потока. Код некорректен. Документация говорит что первый вариант подходит: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, я тоже так думаю и использую первый вариант. Просто где-то пример видел со вторым.